# Drupal Views Ajax Pager Styling Guide

Tags: ajax, drupal, drupal-views

I am using the Ajax pager for views with multiple rows, however the pager looks nasty and whenever a navigation button is clicked the loading animation jumps to the right hand side of the block.

Is there a guide anywhere that outlines how to style the elements of the pager and how to change the animation?

Comment: Are you using a custom theme? Is there a link where this can be debugged?
When you click on any ajax pager element in views, it adds a .views-throbbing class to the link.
The pager itself sits in `<div class="item-list"></div>` and is usually an unordered list (UL) with a .pager class.
Try using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com), it is indispensable for webdeb

Comment: I am using a Zen sub-theme, unfortunately I am working locally and so don't have a link.  I will check out the throbbing class, it is basically the link that I have clicked on plus the blue circle that jump out of place when clicked.  I have been using firebug but can't find a way to get it to pause in the middle of the loading so that I can see exactly what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Firebug, select any of the pager links in it and either add `views-throbbing` if the `<a>` element already has a class -OR- right click on the element and add a new attribute: `class = "views-throbbing"`

[image: Views-throbbing in firebug]

This will all you to have that on and see why the element jumps, without the View doing anything.

I suspect it is a rogue float somewhere in the stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks, it wasn't quite the class I needed but it got me going in the right direction.  I set .progress-disabled to float:none and it fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

When the .views-throbber is slipped into the classes in Drupal 6 it calls these default styles from the

```
html.js a.views-throbbing,
html.js span.views-throbbing {
  background:url(../images/status-active.gif) no-repeat right center;
  padding-right:18px;
}
```

You can override either of these and incase you just want the jumping to stop you can set padding-right:0;